# A question about Invariant subspaces of an algebra.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, invariance

I feel that this is a very simple problem, but somehow I don't see the solution.

I want to show that if $A$ is a subalgebra of $B(H)$ containing $1$ then if $B\in SOTcl(A)$, for every n, $Lat(A^{(n)}) \subseteq Lat(B^{(n)})$.
Where Lat is the set of the invariant subspaces of a set of operators, and $^{(n)}$ means the inflation of an operator or a subset of $B(H)$.

Ok I want to do an induction on the n.

First of all I want to prove the statement for $n=1$.

If $B\in SOTcl(A)$, then exists $B_n \in A$ such that $B_nx\rightarrow Bx\ \ \forall \ x \in X$.

If $B \in A$  surely $Lat(A) \subseteq Lat(B)$. My problem is the passage to the limit...
My ability to go on is blocked!

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are considering the lattice to be the **closed** invariant subspaces. Otherwise I don't think the result is true.

Take  a subspace $M\in\text{Lat}(A)$. Then $B_nM\subset M$. So, for each $x\in M$, the sequence $\{B_nx\}$ is in $M$ and it converges to $Bx$. As $M$ is closed, $Bx\in M$.

The $n$-amplification version runs exactly the same.